# 2 Player Coin Flipping

Tags: java, random, coin-flipping

I'm trying to create a Java program that flips two coins to see who wins the coin flip. It prompts the user for a number of coin flips. If the first player has heads and the second player has tails, then it should output “Player 1 Wins!” and vice versa. If the two players have both heads or tails then it should output “Tie.”. Finally, it should keep track of the number of wins for each player and output the win rates after all coin flips have been made. It feels like the coin flipping part works, but when it displays the final scores for each player, the scores are never right. Can anyone find something wrong?

```
package coinflip;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int flips;
        int flipscount=0;
        int p1score=1;
        int p2score=1;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many flips: ");
        flips=scan.nextInt();

        CoinMethods Coins = new CoinMethods();

        while (flipscount!=flips)
        {
            flipscount++;

            Coins.flip();

            System.out.println(""+Coins.result()+"");

            if (Coins.p1isHeads()&&Coins.p2isTails())
            p1score++;

            if (Coins.p1isTails()&&Coins.p2isHeads())
            p2score++;
        }

        System.out.println("Player 1 won "+p1score+" times!");
        System.out.println("Player 2 won "+p2score+" times!");
    }
}
```

The `CoinMethods` class looks like:

```
package coinflip;

public class CoinMethods {

    private final int HEADS=0;
    private final int TAILS=1;
    private int p1face, p2face;

    public CoinMethods ()
    {
        flip();
    }

    public void flip()
    {
        p1face=(int) (Math.random()*2);
        p2face=(int) (Math.random()*2);
    }

    public boolean p1isHeads (){
        return p1face==HEADS;
    }

    public boolean p2isHeads (){
        return p2face==HEADS;
    }

    public boolean p1isTails (){
        return p1face==TAILS;
    }

    public boolean p2isTails (){
        return p2face==TAILS;
    }

    public String result()
    {
        String results;
        if (p1face==HEADS&&p2face==TAILS)
            {results="Player 1 wins!";
                }
        else
            if ((p1face==HEADS&&p2face==HEADS)||(p1face==TAILS&&p2face==TAILS))
            {results="Tie!";
               }
            else
            {results="Player 2 wins!";
                }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a general comment: your code seems rather verbose. I would have a `Coin` class with a `flip()` method and a boolean variable `isHeads`. Then make two `Coin` instances, `flip()` each one, and compare the `isHeads` variables.

Comment: In what way is it "not right"? Shouldn't the player's scores start at 0?

Comment: It would simplify your problem a lot if you would model the coin with a Boolean variable. You are assuming an unbiased coin anyway, so you don't loose anything. You can define the mapping to be that a "true" coin means head, a "false" coin means tail.

Comment: @antiguru He could do that, but just having a `Coin` class as Jon proposes would be the most obvious improvement and actually lead to shorter and *much* nicer looking code.

Comment: @Voo Sure, I meant that the coin variable is actually encapsulated inside the Coin class, keeping the same interface as it has right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you need to initialize scores to zero instead of one:

```
int p1score=0;
int p2score=0;
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a failure. I guess it helps to have a 2nd pair of eyes look over something. Thanks a bunch for catching that! ^_^

Comment: You're very welcome, that's the reason they suggest pair programing :-)